# What topics would you like to read more about?

Tags: discussion

So I posted [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4804282#4804282) in the chat area and thought I would just go ahead and do it anyway! :)

If you have a specific topic (not too narrow, not too wide!), e.g *see below*, that you'd like to see more questions about then please suggest them here, one per "answer", and someone will work on a question entry/answer for it, I'm sure.

All topics are useful somehow, so rather than down-vote any, try to up-vote those which you would prefer to be discussed.

It's our site, let's build it.

**MOAR CONTENT!**

[image]

;D

Answer (score 3):

This may warrant it's own question, but I've been trying to figure out how to ask more questions about **Table-Image**.

For example, at a tight table, only playing the nutz, but calling down anything, how do I adjust my low-ball style to survive as everything is called down. etc.

Comment: **Table Image**, or as it's often called **Table Dynamics** is a good suggestion. Asking a question on this topic would surely get some attention. +1

Answer (score 2):

**Betting Position** or [betting-positon](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/betting-positon) - Our wiki says...

> Betting position refers to betting/playing strategies based on table
>   position in relationship to the player who is currently the dealer.

It goes further...

> In poker, the player at the Dealer position often has the last bet.
>   Betting and playing-style is affected by the position a player is in
>   relative to the dealer's position.
>
> Questions in this section can apply to playable hands, behaviour in
>   relation to play from other positions, betting and stack sizes in
>   relation to table position, amongst others.

Answer (score 1):

Strategies and questions for **Fast Ring Game Formats** or [rush-poker](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rush-poker), [zoom-poker](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zoom-poker) - Our wiki says...

> A poker variant wherein players are immediately moved to a new table
>   after they finish their turn in the current hand.

More information...

> Playing this format means you’ll be seated randomly among a group of
>   players from the game you selected. The first hand you play will
>   usually be from the big blind. For all subsequent hands, your position
>   will be seated randomly.
>
> If you don’t want to play your hand, and providing you are not facing
>   a bet (i.e. you have the option to check), you can ‘Fast Fold’ to fold
>   right away. If you use ‘Fast Fold’, or fold later in the hand, you
>   will instantly be dealt into a new hand, with a new set of opponents.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as the [**WSOP**](http://www.wsop.com) is underway, are there any questions that people could ask regarding the series?

It's possible that Poker.SE could capitalise on the usual surge in interest over the next few weeks.

Answer (score 0):

**Turning made hands into bluffs**

This topic will likely heavily relate to river play, understanding showdown equity and image manipulation (yours *and* your opponents).